# PHP LDAP member of a group

Tags: php, windows, active-directory, ldap

I have groups and users in windows AD and i would like to check if member is a part of group.
example:

```
user1 is in a group 1
         group 1 in group 2
```

and then i should see user 1 in group 2 as well. In this case i could like to have result 1 or 0
Connection is fine but problem in search statement.

```
$username = $_POST["username"];

$passw = $_POST["password"];


$ldap_dn = " OU=MANAGER GROUP,OU=ALL GROUPS,DC=domain,DC=uk";
$ldap_svr = "domain.uk";
$ldap_domain = "@domain.uk";
$conn=ldap_connect($ldap_svr) or die("Cannot connect to LDAP server!");

ldap_set_option ($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

ldap_bind($conn,$username.$ldap_domain , $passw);


    $filter="(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=Group1,OU=MANAGER GROUP,OU=ALL GROUPS,DC=domain,DC=uk))";
    $justthese = array("cn", "sn", "givenname", "mail");

    $sr=ldap_search($conn, $ldap_dn, $filter, $justthese);

    $info = ldap_get_entries($conn, $sr);

    echo $info["count"]." entries returned\n";
```

Comment: Have a look at [adLDAP](https://github.com/Rich2k/adLDAP) library. It has an inGroup function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this stack-overflow question to see how to solve it without a library: [ldap nested group membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195812/ldap-nested-group-membership)

Basically it boils down to using the LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN matching rule in your query.

`(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Group1,OU=MANAGER GROUP,OU=ALL GROUPS,DC=domain,DC=uk)`