# powershell group inheritance effect

Tags: windows, powershell

In school we need to map network drives using PowerShell. These drives shall be mapped based on group membership. My PowerShell script looks like following:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$groupdomain = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
$user = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current
$GroupName = "year1"
$group = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($groupdomain,$GroupName)
if($user.IsMemberOf($group))
{
    net use S: \\dc\studentinfo\1ABHIT
}
```

I have written something very similar, only with the user being directly added to the group `1AHIT`. In this case the user is added to the group "year1" by group nesting (Group structure: `user --> 1AHIT --> year1`).

The script *works* by checking if the user is member of the group `1AHIT`, which is the group it's been added "manually".

It doesn't work with checking for the nested group. After debugging the code I learned that the `$group` object is the object of the group `year1`, the `if($user.IsMemberOf($group))` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET 3.5 to the rescue with [`UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups).

```
if ($user.GetAuthorizationGroups() -contains $group) 
{
    net use S: \\dc\studentinfo\1ABHIT
}
```

Not directly related but still useful: it's also possible to do this directly with LDAP, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195812/).

Comment: Do i have to instal .NET 3.5 on the whole domain then? Or is it installed on Windows 8.1or higher? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: .NET 3.5 *or higher* needs to be installed only on the machine where you're running this. Windows 8.1 comes with .NET 4.5 preinstalled, so no problem there.

Comment: Thank you very much! You probably saved me from bad grades :D