# PHP LDAP (AD) Search for members of nested groups

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm looking for an possibility to check, if a user is a member of a group or not. The problem ... the group can be nested.

Example:
Group_A is member of Master_Group
Group_B is member of Master_Group
User_A is member of Group_A

I've to check, if User_A is member of Master_Group (or nested Groups).

```
$result = ldap_search($ldap, $_GLOBAL["ldap_BaseDN"], "(????)");
$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
```

Do I have to foreach through every group and check if there is a nested group?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Solution found on this article:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195812/ldap-nested-group-membership Sorry for that question.