# How to find all the groups the user is a member? (LDAP)

Tags: python, ldap, openldap

I am trying to get all the groups that a certain user is a member of.

I have the following *structures* in ldap:

```
o=myOrganization
     ou=unit1
         cn=admin
         cn=guess
```

and

```
ou=users
    cn=ann
    cn=bob
    cn=carla
```

- `myOrganization` is an instance of Organization
- `unit1` is an instance of OrganizationUnit
- `admin` and `guess` are both GroupOfNames and have everyone as a member
- `ann`, `bob`, and `carla` are instances of Person

Currently, I am using the ldap module on python and this is what I have:

```
import ldap
l = ldap.initialize("ldap://my_host")
l.simple_bind_s("[my_dn]", "[my_pass]")
ldap_result = l.search("[BASE_DN]", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(&(objectClass=Person)(cn=ann))", None)
res_type, data = l.result(ldap_result, 0)
print(data)
```

And I am able to get the user `ann`; but, how do I go about getting the groups `Ann` belongs to?

I tried, the following from [this](http://timony.com/mickzblog/2015/08/03/python-ldap-list-the-group-membership-of-a-user/) page:

```
search_filter='(|(&(objectClass=*)(member=cn=ann)))'
results = l.search_s([BASE_DN], ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, search_filter, ['cn',])
```

But I got an empty list. I also tried various combinations of queries, but they all return empty.

PS: I am using OpenLDAP on a linux machine

Comment: _I tried the following from this page... But had no success_.  How, exactly, was the listed query unsuccessful?  Empty results?  Error message?

Comment: Also, are you only looking for groups in which ann is a _direct_ member?  (What if ann is a member of a group which is itself a member of another group?)

Comment: Are you using Windows / Active Directory? If you are, I would suggest using the `pyad` package. I know that it's not particularly helpful to your exact question, but I've found `pyad` to be a much nicer interface than python-ldap. This would be as simple as `user.get_membersOf()` which also allows you to specify a scope and whether or not to include subgroups recursively.

Comment: @JohnGordon I get an empty list when I run the query from the website, and I am only looking for direct members. I will update my question to make it clearer

Comment: @sytech I am using openldap on a linux machine

Comment: I know you specify OpenLDAP, but in case it might help someone else as I struggle very long because of it... With Active Directory you need the distinguishedName all along to get the users with a given membership with such a search_filter... I ultimately find this Q&A that says the same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195812/ldap-nested-group-membership

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`member=cn=ann` is not enough.  You have to use ann's full DN, probably something like this:

```
member=cn=ann,ou=users,dc=company,dc=com
```

Comment: That worked!, another thing that I had to change was `(objectClass=Person)` to `(objectClass=groupOfNames)`