# Query for user in AD using python

Tags: python, scripting, ldap

I am trying to write a python script to validate if a username exists in a particular domain or not .

```
To query :
           username -- > anandabhis
           domain name --> example.com
Output : Successfully verified .
```

For this I have used python-ldap module to connect to LDAP server . But I am unable to proceed further even after reading lots of documentations.

```
import ldap
def test_login(self):
        domain = 'EXAMPLE'
        server = 'ldap-001.example.com'
        admin_username = 'admin'
        admin_password = 'secret-password'
        connection = ldap.initialize('ldap://{0}'.format(server))
        connection.protocol_version = 3
        connection.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
        connection.simple_bind_s('{0}\{1}'.format(domain, admin_username), admin_password)
        search_username = 'anandabhis'
```

Comment: You will have to do a search now.

Comment: @KlausD. I dont know how to search . Can you please help me which function to use ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all the groups the user is a member? (LDAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225230/how-to-find-all-the-groups-the-user-is-a-member-ldap)

Answer (score 1):

A simple search for the sAMAccountName of the user should allow you to get the attributes of the user.

```
user_filter = '(sAMAccountName={})'.format(search_username)
base_dn = 'DC={},DC=com'.format(domain)
result = connection.search_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, user_filter)
print result
```