# VBA LDAP query not returning all groups

Tags: vba, ldap

I am using the following query to pull the groups that a username belongs to:

```
Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Comm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
Conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set Comm.ActiveConnection = Conn
Comm.Properties("Searchscope") = 2

FQDN = "DC=" & Replace(FQDN, ".", ",DC=")

Base = "<LDAP://" & Server & "/" & FQDN & ">"
Fltr = "(&(objectClass=*)" & "(sAMAccountName=" & Username & "))"
Attr = "SAMAccountName, memberof"
Scope = "subtree"

Comm.CommandText = Base & ";" & Fltr & ";" & Attr '& ";" & Scope

Set Response = Comm.Execute
```

This works except that it's not returning all the groups that a user belongs to. I have a user, call him "Kyle", that belongs to "Domain Users" and another group called "RDOC Group" but only the second group is being returned in my query.

I feel like this is a simple thing but changing the scope doesn't seem to be the answer, nor does modifying the filter (at least that I've tried).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the user a direct member in both groups (ie. not via a nested group) ?

Comment: I will have to check when I get back to the office.  I'd bet it's a nested group though because our AD security group management has been horribly neglected for several years.  If it were, will I only get the highest group?

Comment: Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195812/ldap-nested-group-membership

Comment: Or a permission error. I'm d'd if I know how it got that way, but I can't qet group membership for some groups for some users because the query owner doesn't have permission to see that information!  Otherwise identical users, group membership shows ok in other contexts, but my AD query reports non-membership until I go in and change the permission on that data element.

Comment: @TimWilliams, It is nested groups.  Domain Admins is a part of the RDOC Group security group.  I'll take a look at that link and see if I can glean anything from it.