# How to read nested groups in OpenLdap connected to Keycloak

Tags: ldap, keycloak, openldap, nested-groups

I have a Keycloak with an openLDAP User Federation. In the LDAP, I have a user 'someUser' that belongs to multiple groups, namely:

```
dn: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: add
objectclass: groupOfNames
member: cn=architects,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com

dn: cn=architects,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: add
objectclass: groupOfNames
member: uid=someUser,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
```

On my Keycloak, for the LDAP I have created an LDAP Mapper for the roles, like the following

- **Mapper Type** : role-ldap-mapper
- **LDAP Roles DN** : ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
- **Role Name LDAP Attribute** : cn
- **Role Object Classes**: groupOfNames
- **Membership LDAP Attribute**: member Membership
- **Attribute Type** : DN Membership
- **User LDAP Attribute** : uid
- **LDAP Filter**:
- **MODE** : READ_ONLY
- **User Roles Retrieve Strategy**: LOAD_ROLES_BY_MEMBER_ATTRIBUTE
- **Member-Of LDAP Attribute** : memberOf
- **Use Realm Roles Mapping** : ON

The problem is that when I try to get a token on behalf of the user 'someUser' only the role 'architects' appears on the token. Based on the LDAP nesting grouping, I expected that both 'architects' and 'developer' roles would have appear on the token.

Based on other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195812/ldap-nested-group-membership) on similar topics I try to add to the LDAP filter the following:

```
memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941
```

But this seams to only work with Microsoft Active Directory.

My question is, what do I have to do in order to have both roles 'architects' and 'developer' in token? ( besides having to hardcoding them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing member and objectclass in:

```
dn: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: add
objectclass: groupOfURLs
memberURL: ldap:///cn=architects,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com?sub?(objectclass=*)
```

This kind of group defining is called dynamic groups, you should try ldapsearch in your openldap to see if the directory send the correct objects, for example:

```
  ./ldapsearch -h localhost--port 1389 -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w "password" -b "uid=someUser,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com" -s sub "(objectclass=*)" member
```

For more info: https://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch11/dynamic.html

Comment: Thanks for answering, and sorry for the delay. However, when I tried to apply the dynamic groups I ran into "LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object"

Comment: you should declare your object and attributes in your ldap schema in /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema