# Getting only indirect group memberships from LDAP filter

Tags: active-directory

I'm writing a C# method to fetch a user's group membership. I need to know, for each group, whether the user is a direct, or an indirect (due to group nesting) member.

My first attempt:

```
groupSearch.Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={userDistinguishedName})
```

This fetches both direct and indirect group memberships, but there is not way to distinguish the groups as direct or indirect.

My next attempt will be to get a list of only direct memberships, and another list of only indirect memberships, and then concatenate them. I know that a list of direct-only memberships can be fetched with the following filter:

```
groupSearch.Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=group)(member={userDistinguishedName})
```

Is there an equivalent way to get a list of indirect memberships? For example:

```
groupSearch.Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=group)(member-indirect={userDistinguishedName})
```

From [the documentation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) it doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I have found, is to fetch a list of direct memberships and a list of all memberships from AD, and to take the intersection of the two lists (based on the groups' objectGUID), which results in a list of indirect memberships:

```
var userADGroups = _user.FindUserGroups(distinguishedName);
var userADGroups_directOnly = _user.FindUserGroups(distinguishedName, directMembershipOnly: true);
var userADGroups_indirectOnly = userADGroups.Where(x => userADGroups_directOnly.All(y => x.ObjectGuid != y.ObjectGuid));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with using **LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN**

**LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN**  is a matching rule is designed to provide a method to look up the ancestry of an object. Many applications using AD usually work with hierarchical data.

An example of such a query is one designed to check if a user "user1" is a member of group "group1". You would set the base to the user DN (cn=user1, cn=users, dc=x) and the scope to base.

```
(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=Group1,OU=groupsOU,DC=x)
```

find all the groups that "user1" is a member of, set the base to the groups container DN; for example (OU=groupsOU, dc=x) and the scope to subtree.

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=user1,cn=users,DC=x)
```

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax?redirectedfrom=MSDN) Ans and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195812/ldap-nested-group-membership)